# Google Places API error

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, google-places-api

I'm trying to request all places in central London within a radius of 1000 meters using [Google Places API](http://code.google.com/apis/maps/documentation/places), the required output type is XML.
This is my code using JQuery:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>              
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){             
                jQuery.ajax({
                    url: 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/search/xml',
                    dataType: 'xml',
                    type: 'GET',
                    data:  {
                        key: 'MY KEY', 
                        location: '51.526688,-0.123825',
                        radius: 1000,
                        sensor: 'false',
                        types: 'food'
                    },
                    success: function(data){
                        alert("success");
                    },
                    error: function(data){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Unfortunately, I only receive the `error` message. The Firebug console shows me `XML Parsing Error: no element found Location: moz-nullprincipal:{7577ff8b-21cb-40c5-824b-de812540f29e} Line Number 1, Column 1:`.
I have obtained my own API key and turned the `Places API` on. (The website URL is "http://localhost/", since I'm coding local using XAMPP.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot request ressources from different domains using AJAX, it's restricted by same-origin-policy.

Use the maps-API to get the results.

Comment: I mean the javascript-API : http://code.google.com/intl/en/apis/maps/documentation/javascript/places.html